# PhpStorm - why is this case statement unreachable?

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm inspection is claiming that everything after the break in the second case is unreachable.  I don't see why.  What am I missing?

```php
function mymodule_admin_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'taxonomy_overview_terms':
      // We need to add a submit handler to this form so we can save the weight
      // in Mongo.
      $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_admin_taxonomy_overview_submit_mongo';
      break;

      // Unwraps the mymodule News node form
    case 'mymodule_news_node_form':
      $form['#nowrap'] = true;

      $form['field_news_image']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row"><div class="large-5 columns">';
      $form['field_news_image']['#suffix'] = '</div></div>';

      $form['actions']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row"><div class="large-3 columns actions">';
      $form['actions']['#suffix'] = '</div></div>';

      break; // PhpStorm claims everything after this is unreachable ******

      // Unwraps the page forms
    case 'basic_page_with_multiple_images_node_form':
      $form['#nowrap'] = true;

      $form['field_bottom_image']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row"><div class="large-5 columns">';
      $form['field_bottom_image']['#suffix'] = '</div></div>';

      $form['actions']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row"><div class="large-3 columns actions">';
      $form['actions']['#suffix'] = '</div></div>';

      break;

    case 'page_node_form':
      $form['#nowrap'] = true;

      $form['field_bottom_image']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row"><div class="large-5 columns">';
      $form['field_bottom_image']['#suffix'] = '</div></div>';

      $form['actions']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row"><div class="large-3 columns actions">';
      $form['actions']['#suffix'] = '</div></div>';

      break;

    case 'basic_page_with_top_image':
      $form['#nowrap'] = true;

      $form['field_top_image']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row"><div class="large-5 columns">';
      $form['field_top_image']['#suffix'] = '</div></div>';

      $form['actions']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row"><div class="large-3 columns actions">';
      $form['actions']['#suffix'] = '</div></div>';

      break;

    case 'basic_page_with_inline_images_node_form':
      $form['#nowrap'] = true;

      $form['actions']['#prefix'] = '<div class="row"><div class="large-3 columns actions">';
      $form['actions']['#suffix'] = '</div></div>';

      break;
  }
}
```

I hadn't included the rest of the code because stackoverflow was telling me I had too much code for my question.

As you can see there are more conditions after the case in question.  If the first two conditions are not met, the rest should be evaluated, therefor the rest of the code is reachable.  Is this not correct?

Comment: and what's the rest of your code ?

Comment: Umm... Because the break statement terminates the condition? I fail to see: **a)** The rest of your code. **b)** The closing bracket for the switch statement. Maybe the latter is the issue? Accidentally putting everything in the switch? Please post more code for us to give a definitive answer.

Comment: What version do you use? I see no issues at all with your code in v7. **In any case:** pleas try `File | invalidate Caches...` in case you have not done it yet.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne, the Invalidate Caches seems to have fixed it. Version is 6.0.3 - I haven't gotten around to updating to 7 yet.

Comment: LazyOne if you put the Invalidate caches in as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is looking fine here in PhpStorm v7 -- no such error messages at all. And overall code looks fine.

Looks like IDE is out-of-sync (some internal structures) .. so **"File | Invalidate Caches..."** should help here.

P.S.
You can try it when you have "it worked fine yesterday/an hour ago .. and now the same code is broken" kind of situation (especially when upgrading to the newer minor version).